# Mathematica output format

Tags: output-formatting

Basically *Mathematica* is giving me outputs in a format I do not recognise.  I've just started Year 12, so there are mathematical terms I do not understand. For example, `Cot`.

When I type `D[Log[Sin[x]], x]`,  *Mathematica* gives me `Cot[x]`, but I want my answer in the form `Cos[x]/Sin[x]`. I know that they are the same thing, but my teacher has not taught me `Cot` yet. I had to search  on the internet (which I'm obviously not allowed to do under exam conditions). Please help me ASAP as my exam is on the day after tomorrow!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Julia - I doubt mathematica is what you need.  But it sounds like it helped you learn about cot... :)  I suggest you practise past papers.

Comment: If you select `Cot` and press F1 you will get to the help page of `Cot`. In the Details section you will find the relation you are looking for.  Not being allowed to use `Cot` is like saying one may write 1 + 2 but not use 3. At later stage you might want to point your teacher to the [computer based math](http://computerbasedmath.org/) initiative. Good luck with your exam!

Comment: Some of the functions are best memorized.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know about is to use

```
sol = D[Log[Sin[x]], x]
TrigFactorList[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second term in each list is the power. So you read the above as $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$

[reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigFactorList.html)